# Delphi Teechart how to increase line width of second chart

Tags: delphi, teechart

Edit!

Hello !

Im searched through questions on here but was unable to find a way how to increase the linepen width of the second chart. Each chart has 6 series. The first six series in the code below, compiles and works for chart 1. However when i use the commented out code there is an error on compiling the code, a break in the code, or it just doesn't work. There isn't anything under the dock manager that would enable me to do this. I've listed the code that i have tried below.

undeclared identifier series1
undeclared identifier linepen
compiles and runs but doesn't affect the second chart

```
series1.linepen.width := series1.linepen.width  +1 ;
series2.linepen.width := series2.linepen.width  +1 ;
series3.linepen.width := series3.linepen.width  +1 ;
series4.linepen.width := series4.linepen.width  +1 ;
series5.linepen.width := series5.linepen.width  +1 ;
series6.linepen.width := series6.linepen.width  +1 ;

//chart2.series1.linepen.width := 10   (this doesn't work)
//chart2.series[1].linepen.width := 10   (this doesn't work)
//series7.linepen.width := 10 (also not working
```

Comment: Series1.LinePen.Width := 5; is working for me with VCL and and tLineSeries. If you will share the actual code, it may help to find the problem.

Comment: @Reron if you had read the questioin, the first 6 are working as that is linked to chart 1. the next 6 for the second chart however weren't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign property specific for `TLineSeries`, you have to cast general series type:

```
TLineSeries(Chart2.SeriesList[0]).linepen.width := 10
```

Comment: Could not cast an object at 877.1420

Comment: @breitsch Does your chart contain TLineSeries as the first series?

Comment: Yes I do have 2 TLineSeries and a barchart
    chart1.Series[0].Addxy(cnt,tmp,gday,clgreen);
     chart1.Series[1].Addxy(cnt,tmp2,'',clred);
     chart1.Series[2].Addxy(cnt,jar.getjsonobject(jar.length-1-cnt).getdouble('withdrawal'),'',clyellow);

Comment: @breitsch I've never seen such error "Could not cast an object at ...". Does it happen during `TLineSeries(Chart1.SeriesList[0])` casting?  Could you check a type of casted series?